# how to get the whole string matched in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have this code

```
const paragraph = 'my name is bright and this is a testing interface, right.';
const regex = /\b(b)/g;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);
```

What i want is that i want to get the whole word instead of just a single letter.

e.g the output in this code above is **b** which is gotten from the string **bright** in the ***paragraph*** but i don't just want the **b** but the word **bright** as a whole and still be able to manipulate it like make it bolder or something else. Please how do i do it and i have also checked other similar questions on stackoverflow but nothing

Comment: `/\bb\w*/g` might be enough

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OK I will check it

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but will it work if I use js style to change the color or font

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you only want to match words delimited by spaces, this should do the trick.

```
((?:\w)+)
```

Comment: OK I will try that

Comment: This could be written as `\w+` but it does not specify the `b` at the start of the word.